# Normalization on Student database table

Tags: sql, database-design, database-normalization

I have a table that holds student information: the student's name, number, address, courses taken and the instructors and grades from the courses. I want to normalize this table.

What is best practice for this? What will happen to the newly created tables? What are the connections between them?

Comment: What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question? What published DB design textbook/reference/presentation are you following? What are its steps? Where is the first place you are stuck? Right now you are essentially asking us to (re)write a textbook with bespoke tutorial with no details on what you misunderstand or do or don't understand. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs. [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [“help me"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097) [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097)

Comment: "Normalize" with no qualifications doesn't mean anything in particular. What exactly is your assignment? PS [Why is asking a question on "best practice" a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142353/266284)

Answer (score 2):

Start with unique components.

```
Student - Just stuff about the person themselves
Registration - Their registration info, including such things like Major, Minor, etc.
Instructor - Who are the teachers
CourseCategory - Ex: MATH, COMPUTER, ARTS, etc
Course - Each POSSIBLE course  ENG-101, ENG-201, etc
CourseOffering - Each unique offering, such as Each course, timeslot, with whatever instructor at whatever campus.
Enrollment - What student is enrolled in a course offering, status like drop/cancel, final grade (for computing GPA), etc.
```

Each table would have its own auto-increment ID to JOIN to the respective other tables.  You dont want a student record to have columns accounting for 30 classes, their instructors, etc.

Just a sample without more details.  For each table, think of the things that can repeat.  If so, they probably will be their own table with an ID linking to the parent.

Such as Enrollment would have the student ID, Instructor teaching it, the actual course.

Hopefully this gives you enough to chew on before getting question closed out.